# What is the philosophy behind \[Rule] (a.k.a. `->`) for assigning options?

Tags: graphics, syntax, options, language-design

Today I was banging my head against my desk when I realized that the problem I was experiencing was due to having typed

```
ImageSize[Large]
```

instead of

```
ImageSize -> Large
```

This is something that I have never really understood since I started using  Mathematica. What's the difference and is there an obvious reason why some options are "functions" while others are "rules"?

Comment: ... and some are both: `BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]` and   `BaseStyle -> PointSize->Large`

Comment: Well, the reason for `PointSize[Large]` is that it is submitted as directive to `Graphics` and `Graphics3D`; the latter two have their somewhat their own language. I always used to think of options as key-value pairs, even before associations were introduced. When submitting options, the user defined "association" of options `opts` is merged with the default options `defaultopt` like it would be done with `Merge[{opts, defaultopts}, First]`. Maybe that helps you, Kai?

Comment: Wait, when are options functions? Options are always, by definition, specified as rules as far as I can see.

Comment: `Thickness` and `Dashing`  also work both ways: `Graphics[{Dashing -> Small, Thickness[.05], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], 
  Thickness -> .01, Dashing[Large], Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}]}]`

Comment: ... so do `CapForm`, `JoinForm`, `Opacity`

Comment: @SjoerdSmit is correct, options are **always** specified as rules.  If `Graphics` chooses to parse rules as directives that's just some syntactic sugar.  Why are some things options and other things arguments (or even optional arguments)?  That's a good question....

Comment: @JasonB. What's the question then if the claim is false? Kai, can you provide an examples? Otherwise it seems as a simple mistake. p.s. you probably meant function values which have no constraints or graphics directives but still, hard to say without more examples.